# Groovy: General error during conversion : MacroTransformation cannot be run. ( Using Groovy in eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, groovy, geb

I am quite new to the groovy and trying to set up a maven project to automate the web applications using Geb-Groovy-Maven.
So far I have completed the following steps:

1. Created a Groovy project in Eclipse and configured it as Maven project. (Groovy has been installed on eclipse and I've confirmed that programs are running successfully.)
2. Configured the pom.xml file by adding all the required dependencies.
3. Created a new groovy class by right clicking on src file. Wrote the script to launch the webdriver using Geb.

   ```
   import geb.Browser
   import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
   def browser = new Browser(driver: new FirefoxDriver())
   ```

Code:

[image: See the code here]

Error message:

[image: Complete error message]

Comment: Can you show your project in the Package Explorer? You may have different versions of groovy jars but it is hard to tell from you description.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem with Groovy while studying Spring and trying Groovy code examples from the book. Thanks to **emilles** here, I've managed to fix the problem.

I have:

- Eclipse IDE,
- Groovy Development Tools 4.6.0,
- A `'groovy'` plugin defined in my Gradle script,
- `'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.12'` as a Gradle dependency.

In project settings, the Groovy compiler version is 3.0.

What actually helped: `Window > Preferences > Groovy > Compiler > Switch to 3.0.11`.